# nvidia-prime can't switch

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, nvidia-optimus, 18.10

I have a dual boot system with Ubuntu 18.10 and Windows 10, which have GTX 1050 Mobile and Intel HD Graphics 630.

I installed `nvidia-390` driver from a ppa but I can't use my NVidia card even if `prime-select` returns `nvidia`:

```
$> prime-select query
   nvidia
$> sudo lshw -c video | grep configuration
   configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
```

`nvidia smi` shows 410 (I tried before):

[image: smi output]

```
lspci -vnn | grep VGA -A 12
```

[image: lcpi output]

in

> Settings > Details > About

it shows only Intel:

[image: Intel only]

In NVIDIA X Server Settings there are just two options for switching, there is no other tabs like temperature, etc.

[image: my xserver settings screenshot]

I am using CS:GO on Steam for benchmarking and i can get 15-20 fps, while I can get 120 fps in Windows 10.

Comment: Similar problem, my laptop is of Dell XPS15 9370; and I need reboot for switching to Nvidia card